# Use an ATtiny85 instead of an ATtiny13 - Where do I place the XTAL?

Tags: schematics, crystal, attiny

Having looked at a circuit diagram in *Beginners Introduction to the Assembly Language of ATMEL­ AVR ­Microprocessors* by Gerhard Schmidt, I came across a circuit presented by the author (in which an ATtiny13) is used, as below:

[image: Original Schematic, by Schmidt]

Having then looked at [Wikipedia's comparison chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_ATtiny_comparison_chart), the ATMEL datasheet ([Pgs. 29-30](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf)) and elsewhere, the only differences between the two packages I can see are:

1. The '85 has more flash, RAM and EEPROM memory than the '13
2. The '85 <s>requires</s> can use a crystal oscillator (XTAL) or a ceramic resonator connected to pins 3 (Out) and 2 (In), as shown on page 29.

This lead me to modify the schematic to add the crystal, but I'm not sure if I've altered it correctly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ28e2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question I have is this: Is the modification I've made to Schmidt's schematic (adding the crystal and 16pF caps) correct in order for the '13 to be replaced with an '85? (Assume that, physically, the bridge rectifier and VREG portion sit closer to the LED and caps for the crystal, reducing the amount of GND trace between them.)

**EDIT 1**: Having read the comments and *[Choosing the Right Crystal and Caps for your Design](https://blog.adafruit.com/2012/01/24/choosing-the-right-crystal-and-caps-for-your-design/)*, I have come to be aware of the following:

1. An XTAL has a load capacitance, calculated as `CL = (C1*C2) / (C1 + C2) + Cstray`
2. A better way of calculating `C1` and `C2` is `C1, C2 = 2*CL - 2*CStray`
3. The XTAL should be placed as close to the pins as possible (theoretically directly connected to the pins, but in the next holes, for the practical reason of not soldering to the chip's pins).
4. `Cstray` can be estimated to be between `2pF` and `5pF`. (That leaves a margin of error of about `6pF`, which seems more than negligible to me.)

This adds a second part to the question: Is there any way to determine/measure (with some accuracy/small margin of error) what `Cstray` will be, in order to determine what `C1` and `C2` will be?

**Edit 2**: I have also looked at [this question about appropriate caps to use for a microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/151242/load-capacitance-for-a-microcontroller-crystal?rq=1)

Comment: The ATtiny85 does not *require* a crystal.  It can utilize one, but that is only needed if you need accurate timing.  Its fastest peripherals modes are actually only obtainable without.  If you are going to use one, while your circuit might be correct in terms of connectivity, it does not suggest a sound understanding of crystal layout concerns, for example minimizing loop area.  Have a look at some actual designs.  For that matter your schematic has no real organization - it portrays neither clear functionality nor physical geometry.

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisStratton. My main concern was whether the circuit is correct in terms of the crystal's connectivity (although I'll admit the schematic is hard to follow).

Comment: why is the schematic so convoluted?  .... just separating the ground net would make the schematic more readable

Answer (score 3):

As an electronic circuit designer since my young age on 1972, I would say all logic should ever designed from left to right, all entry points, voltage, signal, etc, should come from left and exit on right.  It is very uncommon to see otherwise, and when it is done, confuse the reader.  If you follow this simple rule, helps a lot.  Also, try to make the circuit as squared as possible, ground on the bottom, voltages on the top, avoid create a havoc of lines, straight and plain connections makes everyone understand immediately the circuit. I/O connectors could either be on the bottom or anywhere in the circuit.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the convention/standard.